# Find out what files are in a directory that are "not" listed in the database

Tags: php, sql, database, list

I have a small gallery website but the amount of images in directory differs from that accounted for in database by around 150 so I was wondering if there is a way to find out/list what files are in a directory that are "not" in the database (or vice versa).

basic db structure:

- **images**

  - id
  - images

image names are stored in db as "imagename.jpg"

and the images themselves are stored in images directory

images/

Comment: How does the database table look like? How are the files stored? There's too few information to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put file names from server in one array and files from database in another. Use [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get result.

Example (PHP):

```
$files_db = array("car.jpg", "bike.jpg", "plane.jpg", "ship.jpg", "tank.jpg"); 
$files_server = array("car.jpg", "bike.jpg", "ship.jpg", "rocket.jpg");
```

Use

```
print_r(array_diff($files_db, $files_server));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => plane.jpg
    [4] => tank.jpg
)
```

Or (vice versa)

```
print_r(array_diff($files_server, $files_db));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [3] => rocket.jpg
)
```

Comment: **Note:** You can use `$files_server = scandir('/path/to/images/');` to make the array of files on the server.

Answer (score 2):

If this is likely a one-off problem, I'd solve this with a half-assed solution, using first a little SQL script:

```
SELECT filename FROM images;
```

and ask the database client [`mysql`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) or [`psql`](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/app-psql.html) or whatever to dump the output as plain text to a file. (Shell redirection may do the job if you can't easily find your database client's 'dump to file' command.)

Then I'd get the directory listing:

```
ls /path/to/images/ > ls_files
```

Sort both:

```
sort db_files > db_files.sorted
sort ls_files > ls_files.sorted
```

Then run `diff(1)` to see which files are referenced where:

```
diff -u ls_files.sorted db_files.sorted
```

Lines prefixed with a `+` or `-` are in one but not the other.

You might need edit the SQL output or the `ls` output to get one to match the other. If your editor has a tool like `vim`'s `^V` block select, some of those editing tasks can be simplified, but sometimes just running `ls` from another directory can help prepend the right directory structure in front of every filename.