# Is there a way to find/delete orphan files (that are not listed in the SQL database)?

Tags: php, mysql, file-exists

I have 100K filenames of image files in a MySQL database. The images directory on the server contains 160K images, so there are 60K orphan image files. I want to delete them.

I honestly have no idea how to proceed. The best I have managed so far is to get all the files from the database and then to use `!file_exists()`, but that obviously only considers files that are in the database. The files I am hunting are in the images directory and *not* in the database.

The code below gives you some idea. Obviously there I'm just counting, not deleting, because I'm not looking at the right set of files yet.

```
$Recordset1 = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT imgfile FROM tblimages");

$x=1;
do { 
$filename = '../images/'.$row_Recordset1['imgfile'];;
if(!file_exists($filename)) $x = $x+1;
} while ($row_Recordset1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
echo $x;
```

What I want to happen:

1. Get all filenames from "images" directory
2. Get all filenames from database
3. Compare then delete files that only appear in the images directory.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I found a similar question, but the solution seems to involve manually listing files, which would take weeks in this case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601803/find-out-what-files-are-in-a-directory-that-are-not-listed-in-the-database

Comment: And that's one of the reasons why storing the actual file data in the database, not in the file system and just a path in the database, can be a good idea though some folks here constantly advise otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do this with PHP. It will be easier with shell commands.

First, make a sorted list of all the files and save it to a text file:

```
cd images
find . -type f |sort > ../all-image_files
```

Then make a sorted list of all image filenames in your database

```
mysql -Bn -e "SELECT imgfile FROM tblimages ORDER BY imgfile" > ../db-image-files
```

(not shown: options for username, password, host, and database)

Now find the difference. A good shell tool for this is `comm`.

```
comm -23 ../all-image-files ../db-image-files > ../files-to-delete
```

(read https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm for details)

Then you can review the files-to-delete to make sure you agree with its findings, then delete them:

```
cat ../files-to-delete | xargs rm
```

Comment: Thanks very much Bill. I've never used shell before. I downloaded PuTTY and making slow progress. I'm nervous about deleting 60K files using a tool I'm not familiar with, but backups are in place. Thanks again.